# Ubuntu 16.04 - Recover data from MySQL by moving data folder into Win64 server

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, crossplatform

my Ubuntu 16.04 machine refuses to boot anymore and I'm trying to recover the MySQL data folder.  The MySQL version seems to be 8.0.18 (it was a Bitnami LAMP 7.3.15-0).
My first attempt was to move the data folder to an Ubuntu 18.04 running MySQL 5.7 but the instance refuses to start, saying that metadata in the data dictionary (flags) don't match.
I don't know if similar versions of MySQL are data-compatible across different platforms, now I'd  like to try on a Win64 laptop, so:

1. Can a Win64 MySQL install access the data copied from an Ubuntu server?
2. Assuming the source system was 8.0.18 (Ubuntu), what version of MySQL should I install on the Windows laptop to read the data?

Comment: This is probably more about MySQL than Ubuntu so you might have better luck asking on Stack Overflow or Server Fault

Comment: NO. You need to dump the database to be able to use the data on Windows. You can move the data to another Ubuntu though.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: An Ubuntu VM running MySQL 8.0.18 or newer would be easiest, as it allows you to have a completely disposable environment to work with to extract the data. Create a DB with the same name, stop MySQL, copy the raw files *just for the database you need* to the MySQL data directory, set the permissions, start MySQL. From there, the DB engine will rebuild missing metadata and you should have access to the database again ... assuming there's nothing "special" that was done to the previous MySQL installation.

Comment: @waltinator you're right but in fact the machine crashed just at the end of the `do-release-upgrade` process, in fact after the subsequent reboot (when already upgraded to 18.04) the **ssh daemon** didn't start anymore.  And port 1022 was unusable as well. A bug in the upgrade script I suppose, I think the question refers to 18.04.